# How to use cygwin paths in Windows git hooks?

Tags: windows, git, cygwin

**(A)**
My .git/hooks/pre-commit is

```
#!c:/cygwin/bin/bash.exe
#
/cygdrive/c/tmp/a.sh
```

An error shows when I run 'git commit'

```
.git/hooks/pre-commit: line 8: /cygdrive/c/tmp/a.sh: No such file or directory
```

---

**(B)** If .git/hooks/pre-commit is

```
#!c:/cygwin/bin/bash.exe
#
c:/cygwin/bin/bash.exe /cygdrive/c/tmp/a.sh
```

The error becomes

```
/usr/bin/bash: C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/cygdrive/c/tmp/a.sh: No such file or directory
```

---

**(C)** But in cmd this can run

```
c:\>c:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe /cygdrive/c/tmp/a.sh
```

---

**The question is:** is there a way to run script with cygwin paths from Windows git hooks?

---

Some info below

- git version 1.9.4.msysgit.0
- environment PATH=...;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\cygwin\bin

Answer (score 1):

Found something.

(D) OK if .git/hooks/pre-commit is

```
#!c:/cygwin/bin/bash.exe
#
/c/tmp/a.sh
```

---

(E) Actually the shebang need not be cygwin's.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
/c/tmp/a.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, (D) and (E) work because they use mysisgit's paths (/c/..)

But I would like to use cygwin-only scripts (eg: ruby compass, lftp, which are installed from cygwin).  They still give errors.

```
/c/cygwin/bin/compass: /usr/bin/ruby.exe: bad interpreter: No such file or directory 
mirror: Access failed: /c/Users/.../webroot: No such file or directory
```

So the original question is not yet answered.